# Receiving "Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value" message in logs explorer

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I currently wish to receive notification on my android phone whenever new data are uploaded to the firestore. I am following this tutorial completely (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=If2eDphtutI&t=1178s), however, I am currently stuck at 17:27 part where after I had uploaded data to firebase firestore, my phone does not receive any notification but when I check the logs in the cloud function, I could see the error message "Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value".

The following is my code for my js code:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();

exports.androidPushNotification = 
functions.firestore.document("Notifications/{docId}").onCreate( 
    (snapshot,context) => {
        admin.messaging().sendToTopic(
            "new_user_forums",
            {
                notification: {
                    title: "Codeible.com",
                    body: "Notification Tutorial"
                }
            }
        );
    }
);
```

Comment: Try adding a `return` before `admin.messaging()....`

Answer (score 0):

As @Dharmaraj commented, you'll need to return a promise from the Cloud Function since it contains a call to an API that runs asynchronously. Since it's only one such call, you can do:

```
return admin.messaging().sendToTopic(
  ...
);
```

I recommend reading the Firebase documentation on [sync, async and promises](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions) and watching Doug's video series that is linked from there.